# Creating a method that is simultaneously an instance and class method

Tags: python, methods

In Python, I'd like to be able to create a function that behaves both as a class function and an instance method, but with the ability to change behaviors. The use case for this is for a set of serializable objects and types. As an example:

```
>>> class Thing(object):
    #...
>>> Thing.to_json()
'A'
>>> Thing().to_json()
'B'
```

I know that given the definition of classmethod() in funcobject.c in the Python source, this looks like it'd be simple with a C module. Is there a way to do this from within python?

Thanks!

With the hint of descriptors, I was able to do it with the following code:

```
class combomethod(object):
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method

    def __get__(self, obj=None, objtype=None):
        @functools.wraps(self.method)
        def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if obj is not None:
                return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return self.method(objtype, *args, **kwargs)
        return _wrapper
```

Thank you Alex!

Comment: Why would you need to serialize the *type*?

Comment: there are plenty of reasons. In my particular problem, serializing the type allows us to create the specifications in an RPC system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, you just need to define your own **descriptor** type.  There's an excellent tutorial on Python descriptors [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: For an update 9 years later, the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) now hosts this tutorial from Raymond Hettinger, and it's no longer at the link posted. (One can check archive.org for a cached version of the original, but it's just a slightly smaller version of the one on the Python docs).

Comment: This answer would be magnitudes more useful if it provided an outline solution to question not just a research pointer. It would win my upvote only then.