# Using same function as instance and classmethod in python

Tags: python, decorator, instance, class-method

One can do something like this:

```
class master:
    @combomethod 
    def foo(param):
        param.bar() # Param could be type as well as object

class slaveClass( master ):
    @classmethod 
    def bar(cls):
        print("This is class method")

slaveType = slaveClass
slaveType.foo()

class slaveInstance( master ):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def bar(self):
        print("This is "+self.data+" method")


slaveType = slaveInstance("instance")
slaveType.foo()
```

`combomethod` is defined in "[Creating a method that is simultaneously an instance and class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589690/creating-a-method-that-is-simultaneously-an-instance-and-class-method)".

My question is, why is it like this, that default first parameter can't be used as parameter of comboclass? Or at least, why can't I pass object to classmethod as the first parameter? I know the difference between classmethod and instancemethods, and I know decorators, but I might not understand how built-in `@classmethod` and `self` parameter passing is made. Is there a technical limitation? Or, why isn't `combomethod` allready built in?

Comment: Please don't use text-speak ("smth") in SO posts.

Comment: I cannot make heads nor tails of what you're asking here...

Comment: @Ignacio I want to know if I am doing it all wrong and is there simpler way? I thought there might be some way built in to do the same thing and if not, why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`combomethod` doesn't create a method object when accessed but a specially wrapped function. Like methods each access creates a new object, in this case a new function object.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = 'instance'

    @combomethod 
    def foo(param):
        if isinstance(param, A):
            print("This is an " + param.data + " method.")
        elif param is A:
            print("This is a class method.")

>>> a = A()
>>> A.foo
<function foo at 0x00CFE810>
>>> a.foo
<function foo at 0x00CFE858>

>>> A.foo()
This is a class method.
>>> a.foo()
This is an instance method.
```

It's new for each access:

```
>>> A.foo is A.foo
False
>>> a.foo is a.foo
False
```

`foo` is really `_wrapper` in disguise:

```
>>> A.foo.__code__.co_name
'_wrapper'
```

When called from a class the closure has obj == None (note that 'self' here refers to the combomethod, which has a reference to the original function object in `self.method`):

```
>>> print(*zip(A.foo.__code__.co_freevars, A.foo.__closure__), sep='\n')
('obj', <cell at 0x011983F0: NoneType object at 0x1E1DF8F4>)
('self', <cell at 0x01198530: combomethod object at 0x00D29630>)
('objtype', <cell at 0x00D29D10: type object at 0x01196858>)
```

When called as the attribute of an instance, obj is the instance:

```
>>> print(*zip(a.foo.__code__.co_freevars, a.foo.__closure__), sep='\n')
('obj', <cell at 0x01198570: A object at 0x00D29FD0>)
('self', <cell at 0x01198530: combomethod object at 0x00D29630>)
('objtype', <cell at 0x00D29D10: type object at 0x01196858>)
```

Here is the original function stored in the combomethod:

```
>>> A.foo.__closure__[1].cell_contents.method
<function foo at 0x00D1CB70>
>>> A.foo.__closure__[1].cell_contents.method.__code__.co_name
'foo'
```

`_wrapper` executes `self.method` with either the class or instance as the first argument given the value of obj:

```
if obj is not None:
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
else:
    return self.method(objtype, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: So you told me how combomethod worked and I understood most of it. Thank you for your effort! Could you also tell me, why is it bad and can it be done in any better way? Wrapper around function makes it memory inefficient?

Comment: How is `combomethod` defined or where can it be imported from?

Answer (score 10):

use this:

```
class A(object):

    @classmethod
    def print(cls):
        print 'A'

    def __print(self):
        print 'B'

    def __init__(self):
        self.print = self.__print


a = A()
a.print()
A.print()
```