# How to discriminate between a method called on a class and on an instance?

Tags: python

I have the following problem; I would like to construct a method `bar` which behaves differently, depending whether it is called on an instance or on a class. To be more specific, let us consider the following snippet:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        return "bar called on an instance of Foo"

class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, parents, dct):
        return type.__new__(cls, name, (Foo,), dct)

    def bar(self):
        return "bar called on a class instantiated by Meta"


class A(metaclass=Meta):
    def bar(self):
        return "bar called on an instance of A"
```

Of course, if I create an object of type `A`, `A().bar()`returns `"bar called on an instance of A"`

However, `A.bar()` raises the following error...

```
TypeError: bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

whereas `A.bar(A)` returns `"bar called on a class instantiated by Meta"`. I confess that I don't understand it, since `A` is an object of type `Meta`...

So, how can I correct this piece of code? My question is also a little bit broader: what are the rules to determine whether in an attribute notation `x.y`, `x`is considered as a class or as a method ?

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7373648/2615940) may help shed some light on this for you.

Comment: Are you sure it does not return `bar called on an instance of A`? `A.bar` is going to come first in the mro

Comment: If you make `self.bar` an attribute and the method bar a static of class attribute then they will behave differently depending on whether you use class.bar or instance.bar http://pastebin.com/SdReH161

Comment: @PadraicCunningham : I tested the code with Python3, it didn't work

Comment: @skrrgwasme : thanks, I looked for similar questions, my search was obviously too quick...

Comment: @user19018, http://repl.it/eE9