# How would an instance variable be used in a class method?

Tags: python, instance-variables, class-method

Is there a way that in a class methods I can use an instance variable to perform a calculation?

Very simplified, this is what I am attempting to do:

```
class Test:

  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a

  @classmethod
  def calculate(cls, b):
     return self.a + b
```

Comment: There is no `self` in a class method. Your method would work perfectly fine as a normal instance method. Why push square peg in a round hole? i.e. why do you think you should have a class method, if you are doing calculations on an instance? Your "very simplified" might have been too simplified to understand - all I see is wrong code easily fixable by removing `@classmethod` and replacing `cls` with `self`.

Comment: The `.a` of *which* instance should be used in that method? You don't have a preferred `self` instance, but you could pass an instance (or multiple instances) as explicit parameter to the class function if you really need to.

Comment: The descriptor protocol explicitly allows this; the dot operator will access the `__get__` method of a descriptor with both the instance and the class. See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a method that is simultaneously an instance and class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589690/creating-a-method-that-is-simultaneously-an-instance-and-class-method)

Comment: @Amadan my original problem is something along the lines of instantiating a filename in the init of the class, then using that filename in a classmethod to lazily get a pandas dataframe that will be available for all object instances once opened (to save memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> all I want is to declare a variable 'a', then use it in a class method for calculation purposes.

If you want to cache a class-wide value, these are your basic options:

Set value explicitly:

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def set_foo(cls):
        print('Setting foo')
        cls.foo = 'bar'

    def print_foo(self):
        print(self.__class__.foo)

Foo.set_foo()      # => 'Setting foo'
Foo()
Foo().print_foo()  # => 'bar'
```

Set value at class init:

```
class Foo:
    print('Setting foo')
    foo = 'bar'

    def print_foo(self):
        print(self.__class__.foo)
# => 'Setting foo'

Foo()
Foo()
Foo().print_foo()  # => 'bar'
```

Set value at first instance init:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        if not hasattr(self.__class__, 'foo'):
            print('Setting foo')
            self.__class__.foo = 'bar'

    def print_foo(self):
        print(self.__class__.foo)

Foo()              # => 'Setting foo'
Foo()
Foo().print_foo()  # => 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the namespacing use `@staticmethod` instead and let users pass in the variables e.g. `Test.calculate(a, b)`

Comment: I think my question might've been missunderstood, but all I want is to declare a variable 'a', then use it in a class method for calculation purposes. I think that in my __init__ I should just do Test.a = a.